# Google App Engine terminates after Handling signal: term

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an app deployed as app engine on GCP that calls API, creates Bytes.IO stream and uploads data to the Cloud Storage.  There are 4 files, around 44mb to be uploaded. File is list of urls that then would feed Dataflow but this doesn't really matter. At the beginning I created dictionary with a list for each file, but I thought this could cause some memory issue so now, I create a list, transform to bytes and upload it to GCS. I tried few things, streaming, using discovery Api and gcs library but I keep getting

```
Handling signal: term
```

Any ideas what could cause that? I'm clueless at this point to be honest. Everything works locally, upload of the files doesn't take a lot of time. There is no error, nothing in the logs. If I didn't provide enough info let me know, but not sure what could help.

Comment: Are you using Standard or Flex, could you share the code causing the issue and the configurations being used as the app.yaml? Sometimes this issue is due to lack of memory

Comment: I think it was lack of memory.

Comment: if the issue got solved by increasing the memory could you please share the solution as an answer, this might be useful for other users.

Comment: can you tell us if you solved your problem? I'm having the same problem right now

Comment: @antonioACR1 yeah, I haven't honestly. You need either use bigger instance of App Engine or store less data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different configurations to deploy model to Google cloud run and below worked. Below docker file is used to deploy model for Image captioning with tensorflow model. Initially when tried to deploy in Google Cloud run, I see tensorflow models need larger instances.

```
FROM python:3.9
# # Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./
# expose port
EXPOSE 5000
# Install production dependencies.
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
# RUN pip3 install "uvicorn[standard]" gunicorn
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT main:app --workers 1 --timeout 1200 --preload
CMD exec gunicorn main:app --workers 4 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind :$PORT --timeout 1200
```